# How to create Web to Lead in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a form host on my website (say www.mywebsite.com ) that takes general information for the clients requirements, its having texetboxes, dropdowns, checkbox, radio buttons, etc.
Now I need this data into my salesforce too(as Contacts and Leads)... on form SUBMIT event of this form ... 
what would be best approach to accomplish this task..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

- You can use the [standard Web To Lead functionality](http://na3.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/setting_up_web-to-lead.htm) that Salesforce.com provides and embed its HTML in your form
- You can modify the back end of your website such that when it receives the form, it also creates a lead in Salesforce.com using the API.  You'll find information on integrating to the API from almost every conceivable language on [developer.force.com](http://developer.force.com).